# Detecting VPNs and Proxies via latency

Tags: networking, proxy, vpn

Consider a user who is using a service (say an app backend) and routing their connection through an intermediary proxy and/or vpn. Specifically let’s assume the user is in Shanghai-China, the proxy is in the Dallas-Texas and the backend is on AWS. In theory, compared to a user who actually lives in Dallas-Texas (on the same network) the Shanghai-China user will have additional latency in sending/receiving events due to the Asia<-> USA trip.

Questions:

- Are there known/published methodologies for seeing this additional latency and thereby identifying imposters from far away? The simplest I can think of is grouping by isp providers and then looking for outliers in latency.
- Are there additional ways to honeypot such users? I’m not a network export but I think various sorts of media (eg video streaming) get different treatment on these networks so I’m wondering if it is possible to send additional event data to honeypot more precise latency anomalies.

Assumptions:

- We can assume that we have plenty of user data, from each network provider. We also have streams of event data that includes client and server side timestamps for sending and receiving data.

I’m strictly interested in identifying users who are very far away from the IP source. I am NOT interested in methodologies that strictly try to classify an IP as a VPN (eg what Maxmind does in the above link).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have stated you are not interested in the VPN or Relay identification aspect of it, but only latency detection for "far away" users, I will offer some ideas:

1. *Run your own HTTP(S) measurement server* that all clients must run an HTTP ping against. HTTP round-trips time in milliseconds will be acceptable for broad-strokes classification of a user's "distance" from your server - assuming that the initial TCP handshake has been completed by the client, all intermediaries, and your measurement server ("pre-warmed" connection).
2. *Use an IP geolocation API*. These will give you the country code (almost always accurate), and approximate latitude, longitude (broadly accurate) that you may use to calculate the distance from your server. This of course assumes that the [public IP of the client](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) is visible to you, and not completely obfuscated by the intermediaries.